# RD Web Access to AWS EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, rdp

i have to access my windows server instance hosted on AWS inside the browser so i can use it in the React.js Web App.
My current try is to Access the RD Web Access Service from Windows Server 2019 but i cant activate it i always get the Error:

> Unable to install the role services. ArgumentNotValid: The role, role service, or feature name is not valid: 'MultiPointServerRole'. The name was not found.

Does someone nows the solution for my Problem or does soemwone know how i can access inside my react app a remote screen control of that windows server, i dont mind to use vnc or any other solution.

Thanks all in advance.

Greetings

Philipp